# MCP39F511A Response Contains Unexpected Data Before Correct Packet reading calibration registers

Tags: register, calibration

I'm currently working with the MCP39F511A power monitoring IC and encountering an issue with the serial communication responses I'm receiving. Following the device's manual, I send a packet to request specific data, but the response includes additional, unexpected data preceding the expected packet. I'm hoping to gain some insights into why this occurs and how to handle it.

**Issue Description:**

When sending a packet to the MCP39F511A, I'm expecting a direct response relevant to my request. The packet I send is as follows:

`054d0901a5084100504e1aa66d47`

This packet is intended to request certain measurements from the device. However, the response I receive contains a large amount of data that seems unrelated to my request before finally including the correct response at the end. Here's the response I get:

`050e4b70090803000089c3b3030000150300005207000032ae4014018109000000008ac300000000e70000000000000022ff7f14016809000000008bc300000000ba0000000000000022ff7f14019450061d00000000000000000000000000003412b6cff5b7f4d786d1f9ffb4`

Upon closer inspection, I found that the part I'm actually interested in is at the end of this response:

`061d00000000000000000000000000003412b6cff5b7f4d786d1f9ffb4`

This segment contains the data I requested, and its checksum is correct, indicating that this is indeed the response I was expecting.

**Additional Steps Taken:**

I have cleared the buffer before and after sending the request, as well as before receiving the response, to ensure no leftover data from previous communications would interfere.
I'm using a lock mechanism to ensure that there's only one request being processed at a time, aiming to eliminate the possibility of data mixing from concurrent communications.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone experienced similar issues with MCP39F511A or other serial devices, where the device returns additional, seemingly unrelated data along with the correct response?
2. What could be causing the device to prepend this unexpected data to the response? Could it be related to how the device queues or processes commands?
3. Are there any known strategies or best practices for handling such responses? Specifically, how can I ensure that I'm extracting only the relevant part of the response for further processing?

Any insights, experiences, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm relatively new to working with this specific IC and serial communication in general, so any advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Datasheet says: "Each frame consists of a header byte, the number of bytes in
the frame, command packet...", `054d` doesn't seem ok

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for reply, yeah its not the correct response, it should starting with 06, but in those incorrect responses, I found the correct response in the ending of the response.